# I need to show the subtruction between min and max salary in the Finance Department (for which department_id = 100)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
SELECT last_name, jobs.(max_salary - min_salary)
FROM employees
JOIN jobs ON employees.job_id = jobs.job_id
where department_id = 100
group by jobs.max_salary;
```

**error message:**

> ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
>   01747. 00000 -  "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 1 Column: 24

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

This construct:

```
SELECT last_name, jobs.(max_salary - min_salary)
```

does not make sense.  The dot is used to access a *column* within a table (or view or similar object).  It is not used for an expression.  You construct expressions out of column references.

So, each column references needs to be qualified separately:

```
SELECT last_name, (jobs.max_salary - jobs.min_salary)
```